# Do I need to publish to npm every time I update a package available via git?

Tags: git, publish, npm

Say I maintain an incredible `crab-season` package.  I've `npm publish`ed version 0.1.0 with a `package.json` containing:

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/example/crab-season.git"
}
```

When I add awesome new features, bump the version to 0.2.0, and push to github will the npmjs registry notice my new version or do I need to `npm publish` each time?

Comment: afaik you need to publish each time. `npm` is not connected to `github` or any other version control system.

Comment: `npm`'s got some basic `git` support for things like installing directly from a git url.  I dreamed that since I gave the registry my git url it could check when I push a change that updates the `package.json` version (perhaps with some help from a post receive hook).  Sounds like it'll take some work on my end to get that sort of integration.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After publishing a few modules, the answer is yes, you need to `npm publish` to get new versions on npmjs.

This gives the module author the flexibility to bump their version number as soon as they start work on the next version, or any time before the version is finished.

[`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) handily speeds up this flow by detecting a git repository, bumping the version in `package.json`, committing the change, and tagging the change with the version number.

Answer (score 43):

Travis CI can publish to npm when you push a version tag to reduce the overhead of releasing a change.  Enable in your `.travis.yml` with:

```
deploy: 
  provider: npm
  api_key: "YOUR API KEY"
  on:
    - tags: true
```

Check the [travis docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/deployment/npm/) for details.  There's also a step-by-step guide in [this post](http://mclear.co.uk/2013/10/06/publishing-to-npm-on-git-commit-using-github-hooks-and-travis/).

Comment: `$ travis setup npm` adds the above using the [travis gem](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb)

Comment: That's... beautiful.