# How do I update an NPM module that I published?

Tags: module, npm

I created a NPM module and I published it at version 0.0.1

I made some changes and pushed those to github, and I would like it so that when one uses `npm install myModule` the new version is used.

How do I tell NPM that there is a version 0.0.2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to publish to npm every time I update a package available via git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507763/do-i-need-to-publish-to-npm-every-time-i-update-a-package-available-via-git)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Change the version in your `package.json` or use `npm version <new-version>`.

After changing the version number in your `package.json`, you can run `npm publish` to publish the new version to NPM.

`npm install` will install the latest version in the NPM repository.

Comment: @AmirRezvani: You still need to change the version & publish.

Comment: This took me a surprisingly long time to find an answer to....

Answer (score 34):

Increase the version number and then run `npm publish yourModule` again - as described in the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish).

`npm install yourModule` will then install the latest version from the NPM registry.

I found the last answer a little misleading, sorry.

Comment: how do you increase the version number?

Comment: `npm version 0.2.0` or `npm version patch`

Comment: @emarel How to increase the version number: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning

Comment: You also need a `npm login` if you're not logged in

Answer (score 10):

For me, updating the version in the `package.json` still resulted in the "You cannot publish over..." error.

The steps to resolve were (based on ops version number):

1. `npm version 0.0.2`
2. `npm publish`

Answer (score 9):

1. If it is an patch release (small changes) use following:

   ```
    npm version patch
   ```

   It will increment the last part of version number.
2. If it is a minor release (new features) use following:

   ```
    npm version minor
   ```

   It will increment the middle part of version number.
3. If it is a major release (major features or major issue fixes) use following:

   ```
    npm version major
   ```

   It will increment the first part of version number.

Answer (score 6):

From the [npmjs documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-your-published-package-version-number):

1. To change the version number in **package.json**, on the command line,
   in the package root directory, run the following command, replacing
   **<update_type>** with one of the [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) release types
   (patch, major, or minor):

   > `npm version <update_type>`
2. Run **npm publish**.
3. Go to your package page (**https://npmjs.com/package/**) to check that the package version has been updated.