# How often can I publish to npm?

Tags: npm

Currently I am publishing a new version of my NPM package every time I push changes to the GIT repository. Most of my changes are just silly patches. I use NPM as a tool that enables versioning and code reuse across many of my projects. I am already over some v0.0.173 after a month of work. Is this safe to keep publishing stuff at the same pace? Are there any gudelines or anything that regulates how often a package can be published? I don't want to get banned just because I didn't know the rules.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507763/do-i-need-to-publish-to-npm-every-time-i-update-a-package-available-via-git The question and answer seem to suggest, yes that you can publish very often.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want to get banned just because I didn't know the rules.

You can find a [code of conduct on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/conduct). Squatting is forbidden (reserve a name by publishing an empty package), packages must not contain illegal or infringing content, packages must not be malware, etc. but **there is no restriction on how often a package can be published**.

Here is an excerpt:

> The Service administrators reserve the right to make judgment calls
> about what is and isn't appropriate in published packages. These are
> guidelines to help you be successful in our community.
>
> Packages published to the Service must be created using the npm
> command-line client, or a functionally equivalent implementation. For
> example, a "package" must not be a PNG or JPEG image, movie file, or
> text document. Using the Service as a personal general-purpose
> database is also not allowed for this reason. Packages should be npm
> packages, and nothing else.
>
> Packages must contain some functionality. "Squatting", that is,
> publishing an empty package to "reserve" a name, is not allowed.
>
> Packages must not contain illegal or infringing content. You should
> only publish packages or other materials to the Service if you have
> the right to do so. This includes complying with all software license
> agreements or other intellectual property restrictions. For example,
> redistributing an MIT-licensed module with the copyright notice
> removed, would not be allowed. You will be responsible for any
> violation of laws or others’ intellectual property rights.
>
> Packages must not be malware. For example, a package which is designed
> to maliciously exploit or damage computer systems, is not allowed.
> However, an explicitly documented penetration testing library designed
> to be used for white-hat security research would most likely be fine.
>
> Package name, description, and other visible metadata must not include
> abusive, inappropriate, or harassing content.